# Card game rule: the hand is drawn from a pack of cards (no jokers). Play cards ONLY when they are

Tags: java, matrix

**Help me how to take the input. I can not understand what to add in the main method**

Card game rule: the hand is drawn from a pack of cards (no jokers). Play cards ONLY when they are  3 of a kind (...AAA... ) or 4 of a kind(...AAAA...).  a straight flush of 3 or more cards(...JQK... or ...A23456…... in the same suit).  Find out whether the player will be able to play the whole hand

```
//input a 4X13 matrix with 4 suits and 13 ranks of cards. set cards[suit][rank] to 1 if this card in hand.
public static boolean handClear(int[][] cards, int hand) {
    if(hand == 0) return true;
    for(int rank = 12; rank >= 0; rank--) {
        for(int suit = 0; suit < 4; suit++) {
            if(cards[suit][rank] == 1) { //if cards[suit][rank] in hand
                cards[suit][rank] = 0; hand--;
                int smallerRank = rank == 0 ? 12: rank - 1; // look for straight flush that end with this card
                // watch for Ace as a special case that ***QKA and A23*** both valid
                if(cards[suit][smallerRank] == 1) {
                    cards[suit][smallerRank] = 0; hand--;
                    int r = smallerRank - 1;
                    for(; r >= 0 && cards[suit][r] == 1; r--) {   //try playing the straight flush found
                        cards[suit][r] = 0; hand--;
                        if(handClear(cards, hand)) return true;
                    }
                    r++;
                    for(; r <= smallerRank; r++) {  //backtrack if play did not work
                        cards[suit][r] = 1; hand++;
                    }
                }
                //look for 3/4 of a kind for cards[suit][rand]
                int n = cards[0][rank] + cards[1][rank] + cards[2][rank] + cards[3][rank];
                if(n == 3 || n == 2) {
                    int tmp1 = cards[(suit + 1) % 4][rank],
                        tmp2 = cards[(suit + 2) % 4][rank],
                        tmp3 = cards[(suit + 3) % 4][rank];
                    cards[(suit + 1) % 4][rank] = 0; //try playing the 3/4 of a kind
                    cards[(suit + 2) % 4][rank] = 0;
                    cards[(suit + 3) % 4][rank] = 0;
                    hand -= n;
                    if(handClear(cards, hand)) return true;
                    cards[(suit + 1) % 4][rank] = tmp1;   //backtrack if play did not work
                    cards[(suit + 2) % 4][rank] = tmp2;
                    cards[(suit + 3) % 4][rank] = tmp3;
                    hand += n;
                }
                cards[suit][rank] = 1; hand++;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I am just not understanding how to take the INPUT for this program.

Comment: You mean how to test your method ?

Comment: Yes. Can you help me?

Comment: Have you created a class ? a `main()` method ?

Comment: No. I did not create main method. I am new to java. What should I write in that now?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just want an explanation of how to initially call the method, that you posted in your question.

The method parameter `cards` represents all the cards in a deck.
There are four suits, i.e. Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts and Spades.
Obviously each suit has an associated index. As I understand the code you posted, it is OK to simply associate an index with a suit, arbitrarily. So let's assume the following:

0 = Clubs
1 = Diamonds
2 = Hearts
3 = Spades

Hence the dimensions of the array `cards` should be 4 and 13, since there are thirteen cards in each suit. So you need to create a two-dimensional array, e.g.

```java
int[][] cards = new int[4][13];
```

Now you need to associate a card in a suit with an index. Let's assume that the Ace has index 0 (zero) and that the King has index 12 (twelve).

This means that `cards[0][0]` represents the Ace of Clubs and `cards[2][10]` represents the Jack of Hearts.

My Poker knowledge is a bit rusty, so I may be wrong, but a Poker hand consists of five cards.

So you need to initialize `cards` and set each element to 0 (zero), i.e.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
        cards[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

Now you need to "deal" a hand. You need to set the value in `cards` to 1 (one) for the index of the card. How you deal the cards randomly, I don't know but let's say you dealt yourself a 7 of Spades, that would mean you need to do the following.

```java
cards[3][6] = 1;
```

Note that the method you posted, i.e. `handClear`, is a recursive method. That means the method calls itself. All recursive methods must have a condition that terminates the recursion. In method `handClear` that condition is when the [method] parameter `hand` equals 0 (zero). That means that the value of `hand` must be the number of cards in the hand that was "dealt". As I said earlier, for Poker, I believe it is five. But it doesn't matter since the method `handClear` will handle any value of parameter `hand` that it receives.

So in order to initially call method `handClear`, you need to determine how many cards make up a hand, for example 5 for Poker. Then you have to create the two-dimensional array and initialize it as I explained above, and finally you have to select `hand` different elements in `cards` and set the element value to 1 (one). Then you can call method `handClear`.

A very simple example of the above:

```java
int[][] cards = new int[4][13];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
        cards[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
int hand = 5;
cards[0][0] = 1; // Ace of Clubs
cards[1][0] = 1; // Ace of Diamonds
cards[2][0] = 1; // Ace of Hearts
cards[3][0] = 1; // Ace of Spades
cards[0][1] = 1; // Two of Clubs
if (handClear(cards, hand)) {
    System.out.println("You have a winning hand!");
}
```